# How I can read numbers from text file in specific lines?

Tags: c#

this is my text file:

```
Earnings: 17 

EarningsM: 2

Level: 6
```

How can I set this numbers for integers?

I tried

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\makeeuro\work.txt"))
    if (line.Contains("Earnings"))
        button1.Text = line;
```

but I need only numbers, so it's now working correctly. This is my integers:

```
int xp;
int lvlg;
int lvl;
```

I need to put "Earnings" value for xp, "EarningsM" for lvlg and "Level" for lvl.

Comment: are the values always going to be in this format?

Comment: I recomment you use braces around if you have nested loops and conditons. `foreach(...) { if (statement) ... } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\makeeuro\work.txt");
Dictionary<string, int> values = lines
    .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
    .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => int.Parse(split[1]));
```

Then you'll be able to access your integer values by name like this:

```
int xp = values["Earnings"];
```

and so forth.

Of course this is very crude and does no error checking, which I'll leave to you as an exercise ;-)

A bit of explanation about the Linq operators:

The `Where` operator gets rid of empty lines.

The `Select` operator splits each line at the `:`, and projects it into an array containing two string, the key and the value.

The `ToDictionary` operator creates the dictionary by selecting the first item of the split as the key, and the second as the value.

Cheers

Comment: You would need to also add a `.Trim()` to `split[1]` to remove the space.

Comment: @Enigmativity Actually, int.Parse() "eats" the space. As per MSDN, the format is "[ws][sign]digits[ws]".

Comment: @LucMorin - That's something I didn't know. All these years of trimming!